# XSD Keyref field only works with ".", instead of element name?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

Why are the below schemas different? I am just trying to make a simple keyref, and I can provide more context if necessary...

```
<!-- This works -->
<xsd:keyref name="followsKey" refer="userKey">
    <xsd:selector xpath="user/follows" />
    <xsd:field xpath="." />
</xsd:keyref>

<!-- This doesn't -->
<xsd:keyref name="followsKey" refer="userKey">
    <xsd:selector xpath="user" />
    <xsd:field xpath="@follows" />
</xsd:keyref>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different in that one refers to an element named "follows", the other refers to an attribute named "follows".

If the second one were written `<xsd:field xpath="follows"/>`, it would differ from the first in that it would only work if a `user` element has a single `follows` element child, whereas the first allows a `user` to have multiple `follows` children, each of which acts as a keyref.

Comment: I also tried using ``follows`` without the at symbol, but alas, there are multiple ``follows`` children. Thanks for the explanation!